# routerLink dinamico angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

```html
<a *ngFor="let titulo of titulos" class="title-breadcrumb" [routerLink]="titulo.url != '' ? titulo.url : ''"> {{titulo.label}}</a>
```

Lo que necesito y no estoy pudiendo hacer, es que el **atributo routerLink**, **solo este** cuando la propiedad titulo.url exista o no sea vacio. En caso de ser **vacio o no exista, no quiero que este** la propiedad routerLink. No se como hacerlo ya que estoy usando un for para recorrer un array y renderizar las etiquetas "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es hacer la iteración con un `ng-container` y dentro tener dos etiquetas `a`, y mostrar una o la otra según la url esté o no vacía.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let titulo of titulos">
      <a class="title-breadcrumb" *ngIf="!!!titulo.url">
        {{titulo.label}}
      </a>
      <a class="title-breadcrumb" *ngIf="!!titulo.url" [routerLink]="titulo.url">
        {{titulo.label}}
      </a>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: el problema que lo que tiene que ser el for, es el A. Porque es un breadcrumb digamos, quedan un enlace al lado del otro

Comment: No debería afectar. `ng-container` no se renderiza. Al final siempre quedarán los `a` uno al lado de otro.

Comment: podrias ayudarme con este https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457008/cancelar-peticiones-angular-interceptor

Comment: @DiegoFerrer Te ayudaría con gusto pero el proceso es complejo y no tengo el tiempo suficiente.

Comment: Ya lo solucione este actual, el que te acabo de pasar es el que no pude solucionar